# Increment wrt TCC , GCC

Tags: c, increment, ansi-c

I am skipping header files and void main...
Code 1:-

```
int a = 5 , c ;
c = a++ + ++a + a++;
a = 5;
printf("%d %d",a++ + ++a + a++ , c);
___________________________________________________
```

Outputs:-
    TCC:- (Yes Borlands 3.0 or whatever it is called one for DOS-blue environment)
    19 18 
    19 = how ? 5+7+7 and if yes (definitely compared to GCC output) but why not 18?

18 = 6+6+6 ? (c assignment code equivalent to 
                  a++;
                  c=a+a+a;
                  a++;
                  a++;) right ?
    and why 19 18 ? two different values for exactly same code ? 
GCC:- 
    19 19 
    19 both 5+7+7 ? makes sense..

Now , Code 2:-

```
int a = 5 , c ;
c = ++a + ++a + ++a;
a = 5;
printf("%d %d",++a + ++a + ++a, c);
_________________________________________________
```

TCC:- 
    24 24 
    24 with same logic 8+8+8(c assignment code equivalent to 
                  a++;
                  a++;
                  a++;
                  c=a+a+a;
                  ) and a = 8 ;

GCC:-
    22 22 
    22 ? how ? by normal logic 6 + 7 + 8 = 21 but output 22 ?
       then 6+8+8 and if yes how ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067722/a-weird-behavior-of-c-compilers-gcc-and-turbo

That may be relevant. It is (or at least, it seems to be) to do with an undefined order of operations taking place.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233

Comment: @Luke it is bit relevant , yet i am not changing value of 'a' between two arguments of function call 'printf()'  , 'c' is calculated separately and then 'a' is reset to 5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Different compilers execute expression in their own manner. Compilers execute statements with **Optimization** Ideally, we should not compare behaviour of compiler versions i.e. TCC, GCC, Borland c etc

The order of execution may  change from compiler to compiler depending on optimization techniques

Reference answer : [Very Nice Explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540468/1994950)

For exam point of view, we should follow textbook standard in this type of questions

Comment: so it is possible that  optimization for 'c = a++ + ++a + a++;'  is different than optimization of 'a++ + ++a + a++' in function call wrt TCC (even though calculation is exactly same) and hence two ans viz. 18 19 are generated ?

Comment: yes.. because at time of executing `second` statement, compiler may have taken different order keeping optimization techniques in mind

Comment: The code the OP has exhibits Undefined Behavior.